# set Timepicker and trigger the set time with http request

Tags: flutter

Hi i would like to ask how to trigger my set time in my time picker and make a http request when the time set was trigger 
   import 'dart:async';

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

//This code is here is use to get the time the user want

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay.now();
  TimeOfDay picked;
  Future<Null> selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    picked = await showTimePicker(
    context: context, 
    initialTime: _time,
    );
    setState(() {
     print(_time);
      print(picked);

    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the below code. When a time is set using the time picker, a network request is made and the result is displayed when available.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:timepicker/post.dart';
import 'package:timepicker/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TimeOfDay _selectedTime = TimeOfDay.now();
  String postTitle = "";

  Future<Null> selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: _selectedTime,
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != _selectedTime) {
      print(picked);
      Post post = await getPost();
      setState(() {
        _selectedTime = picked;
        postTitle = post.title;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("${_selectedTime.toString()}"),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => selectTime(context),
              child: Text("Select time"),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Text('$postTitle'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**post.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

Post postFromJson(String str) => Post.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String postToJson(Post data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Post {
  int userId;
  int id;
  String title;
  String body;

  Post({
    this.userId,
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.body,
  });

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Post(
        userId: json["userId"],
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        body: json["body"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "userId": userId,
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "body": body,
      };
}
```

**services.dart**

```
import 'package:timepicker/post.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

Future<Post> getPost() async {
  final response = await http.get('$url/1');
  return postFromJson(response.body);
}
```

Comment: when the time is reach it will trigger a http request?

Comment: hi sir sorry i miss my question is lacking when i post it i forgot to put my app is like alarm clock when the set time is reach it will trigger the request

Comment: Oh..will change this accordingly tommorow

Comment: Okay sir sorry i had almost forget it

Comment: Sir can you help me please?